# Expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int **'

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am getting a compiler error on my program . I use Dev-C++ with -c99 -wall and -pedantic .

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int size,dial,isListEmpty=0,init,i,variableSize,totalSize=0;//Some values I am using 

    printf("Welcome to your New Phone ! Please select the size of contact list\n");//Welcome Message

    scanf("%d", &size);//input of size

    int *listFirstName = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));//Last name (in numbers)

    int *listLastName = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));// First name in numbers

    int *listNumber = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));// the phone number

    for (init=0 ; init< size ; init++){//initialization of arrays

        listFirstName[init]=-1;

        listLastName[init]=-1;

        listNumber[init]=-1;

    }
```

This is where the compiler shows that there is an error.

```
                        if (dial==3){

        int linearAnswer,possibleLN=0, possibleFN=0,flag=0,j=0;

        printf("Would you like to search by Last Name , First Name? Please press 1 or 2\n");

        scanf("%d",&linearAnswer);

        if(linearAnswer==1){

            scanf("%d",&possibleLN);

            while(j<size){

                if(listLastName[j]==possibleLN){

                    variableSize=j+1;

                    printf("%d",variableSize);

                    printf("\nLast Name:%d\t",&listLastName);

                    printf("First Name:%d\t",&listFirstName);

                    printf("Phone Number:%d",&listNumber);

                    flag=1;

                }

                j++;

            }
```

### The compiler error :

[Warning] format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int **' [-Wformat=]

---

What does the program do : It copies some basic functions of a phone from 1990s . First , the user selects the size of the contact list . Then he gets to add a contact,  find a contact or list all contacts or exit.

Edit : Removed the pictures and added more detail

Comment: I forgot to add , the for loop in the initialization does close with a bracket . It doesn't show in the picture.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ AND http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode AND http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Don't provide  source or error messages in pictures - Provide them as properly formatted text with your question, otherwise many people won't even look at your code.

Comment: "I forgot" Try [edit].

Comment: It seems to be a warning, not an error. Check if your lib/executable is being generated.

Comment: How do you write *Elijah* as a decimal number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listNumber is declared as a pointer to an int: `int*`.
`&listNumer` is of type `int**`.
printf needs an `int` as parameter for a `%d`.

What you probably wanted to do is:
`printf("%d", *listLastName);`

The `*` dereferences listLastName, i.e. lets you access the int value.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I understand the issue now.